# Having trouble with a slow MongoDB aggregation query

Tags: performance, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following aggregation query in MongoDB

```
return mongoose.model('Submission')
  .aggregate([
    { $match: { client: { $in: clientIds }, admin: this._admin._id } },
    { $sort: { client: 1, submitted: -1 } },
    { $group: {
      _id: '$client',
      lastSubmitted: { $first: '$submitted' },
      timezone: { $first: '$timezone' },
    } },
  ])
  .exec();
```

which is performing really badly on a collection with about 2000 documents. It  usually takes 5 seconds to complete and I've seen as bad as 15 seconds. I have the following index on the submissions collection:

```
{
  client      :  1,
  admin       :  1,
  assessment  :  1,
  submitted   : -1,
}
```

I'm stuck as to why it's taking so long. Any suggestions?

EDIT

I've run the query

```
db.submissions.aggregate([
  {$match: {
    client: {$in: ['54a4cdfdd0666c243035dc98','55cc985291a0ffab6849de34']}, 
    admin: '542b4af8880fc300007eb411'
  }}, 
  {$sort: {client:1, submitted: -1}}, 
  {$group: {
    _id: '$client', 
    lastSubmitted: {$first: '$submitted'}, 
    timezone: {$first: '$timezone'}
  }}
], {explain: true})
```

in the shell with explain and got

```
{
  "stages" : [
    {
      "$cursor" : {
        "query" : {
          "client" : {
            "$in" : [
              "54a4cdfdd0666c243035dc98",
              "55cc985291a0ffab6849de34"
            ]
          },
          "admin" : "542b4af8880fc300007eb411"
        },
        "fields" : {
          "client" : 1,
          "submitted" : 1,
          "timezone" : 1,
          "_id" : 0
        },
        "queryPlanner" : {
          "plannerVersion" : 1,
          "namespace" : "webdemo.submissions",
          "indexFilterSet" : false,
          "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [
              {
                "admin" : {
                  "$eq" : "542b4af8880fc300007eb411"
                }
              },
              {
                "client" : {
                  "$in" : [
                    "54a4cdfdd0666c243035dc98",
                    "55cc985291a0ffab6849de34"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "inputStage" : {
              "stage" : "IXSCAN",
              "keyPattern" : {
                "client" : 1,
                "admin" : 1,
                "assessment" : 1,
                "submitted" : -1
              },
              "indexName" : "client_1_admin_1_assessment_1_submitted_-1",
              "isMultiKey" : false,
              "direction" : "forward",
              "indexBounds" : {
                "client" : [
                  "[\"54a4cdfdd0666c243035dc98\", \"54a4cdfdd0666c243035dc98\"]",
                  "[\"55cc985291a0ffab6849de34\", \"55cc985291a0ffab6849de34\"]"
                ],
                "admin" : [
                  "[\"542b4af8880fc300007eb411\", \"542b4af8880fc300007eb411\"]"
                ],
                "assessment" : [
                  "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                ],
                "submitted" : [
                  "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "$sort" : {
        "sortKey" : {
          "client" : 1,
          "submitted" : -1
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "$group" : {
        "_id" : "$client",
        "lastSubmitted" : {
          "$first" : "$submitted"
        },
        "timezone" : {
          "$first" : "$timezone"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "ok" : 1
}
```

EDIT 2

The output I get from `db.submissions.getIndices()` is

```
[
  {
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
      "_id" : 1
    },
    "name" : "_id_",
    "ns" : "webdemo.submissions"
  },
  {
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
      "client" : 1,
      "admin" : 1,
      "assessment" : 1,
      "submitted" : -1
    },
    "name" : "client_1_admin_1_assessment_1_submitted_-1",
    "ns" : "webdemo.submissions",
    "background" : true
  }
]
```

Comment: Try to include the [**`explain`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) option in the [**`db.collection.aggregate()`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) method in mongo shell.

Comment: @chridam I've updated my question with the output from explain

Comment: Please add the output of `db.submission.getIndices()`. My bet goes on the sort stage.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I've updated my post with the indices.